# How to make clear that I'm not being passive-aggressive and that accusing me of that is hurtful

Tags: relationships, conflicts

My SO is hungry for a leftover gyro from earlier. I heat it up along with a taco. I can't say exactly why I made a decision to serve the taco; I just figure it was leftover too, so one of us will eat it, with my partner taking priority over me (since the initial action was already going to be for them). When I bring the plate, they are taken aback in a particularly unpleasant way. I'm told I'm being passive-aggressive, that I brought the taco just so we could both have half of everything, when they never wanted the taco and were only expecting a gyro (which getting half taken from would be understandably upsetting). I try to explain that I don't care what of it I would eat, that I didn't make any of it for me, but this is met with a smirk and an assessment that I had been "called out on [my] shit". This makes my blood boil. Not long after, I'm offered a bite of the gyro, given to me with a slight smile, which I already know is sort of like a peace offering, but I decide to not relent because I am bothered this even went this way, and from here on it's escalated.

I truly did make the taco for them first, though I would eat it if they didn't want it; this would be the ideal scenario, me offering and them taking it or leaving it. I would like to know if this really is passive-aggressive behavior, because I just see it as courtesy. Otherwise I would like to know a way to de-escalate. I don't like to change or regret how I went about doing things - I don't believe I did anything wrong until becoming upset - though when these things happen it does seem to create a barrier because it feels like I don't have the freedom to do something I see as harmless. Obviously the problem is that my partner sees some ulterior motive, so I'd be welcome to any advice that could help me clarify this.

Comment: I don't fully understand what exactly you are asking here. Can you maybe add a clear question and also the goals that you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure what you're asking here. Are you asking how to offer food without giving the wrong assumption you want some yourself too? Are you asking how to de-escalate things in general (out of scope as too broad)? Are you asking how not te get upset at some teasing from your SO (intrApersonal so out of scope for this site as well)? This question has good potential but needs a more specific goal to achieve.

Comment: it is obvious they are asking how to better communicate their lack of deviousness to their SO, however its unlikely they will be able to and should probably confront them about their paranoia, as it implies a lack of trust and that must stem from somewhere. Fix that and the problem goes away.